Kitchen drawer only comes out half-way
I have a kitchen drawer that only comes out half-way, seeming to catch on the right side, while the left side can come out a little further.
I suspect that there is a screw behind the front roller that has come out of the cabinet carcasse a little, and is catching on the back roller.  However, despite pushing a length of stiff plastic packaging strapping into the gap, to form a ramp to push the screw beneath the rear roller, I haven't been able to get it out.
How can I get this drawer (the upper drawer in the included photo) out without breaking things?


Try taking the bottom drawer out to see if you can reach anything from underneath.

@RMDman I've tried that.  It's catching somewhere inside the C-channel, and I can't even see in there with a torch, much less get anything thicker than a piece of packing strap in there.

Remove the lower drawer and attack the loose screw from below perhaps using an oscillating tool behind the channel.

I might be able to try a hacksaw blade...
